# Net::HTTP.post_form() doesn’t submit parameters to server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I’m using Rails to post some form data to a web service running php with the Slim framework. My problem is that `Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, data)` doesn’t submit the data correctly to the server.

My code looks like this:

**Rails:**

```
url = URI.parse("http://somewhere.com/login")
username = "my username"
password = "my password"

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, username: username, password: password)
```

**Update:**
Changing the call to 
`response = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, { 'username' => username, 'password' => password } )` as per suggestion from Jon and taglia doesn’t work either.

I even tried to build the request manually like so:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
req.body = "username=#{username}&password=#{password}"
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http| http.request(req)}
```

With the same result that the parameters are not correctly sent to my web service.

**Slim:**

```
$app->post('/login', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app, $authenticator) {
  $user_params = $request->getQueryParams();
  var_dump($user_params);
  echo $authenticator->login($user_params);
}); // login
```

The thing is the Slim side is working. I tested it with Chrome’s Advanced Rest Client App.

Using Rails the `var_dump()`results in `array(0)`. So obviously no parameters are submitted to the server.

Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Net::HTTP.post_form(url, username, password) ?

Comment: According to the documentation for `post_form` ... **The form data must be provided as a Hash mapping from String to String**. You are using a symbol to string mapping.

Comment: @Jon is right, and you are also not providing the data as a Hash. Your code should be: `response = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, { 'username' => username, 'password' => password } )`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying same scenario with `Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.mailtester.com/testmail.php'), { 'q' => "santosh8887@gmailsdfsfd.com", 'submit' => 'Check address', 'action' => 'testmail.php', 'method' => "post" })`
Its giving me result like `#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>`